# charAt(i--), get value at (i-1) or i?

Tags: java

When I run the following code:

```
int i = s1.length()-1, j = s2.length()-1;
int t1, t2, c=0;
while(i>=0||j>=0) {
    t1=Character.getNumericValue(i<s1.length() ? s1.charAt(i--) : '0');
    t2=Character.getNumericValue(j<s2.length() ? s2.charAt(j--) : '0');
    c = (t1 + t2) > 1 ? 1 : 0;
    res.append(t1^t2 + c);
}
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: `i--` evaluates the value of `i` before the decrement, in case you're still wondering. By the way, that code is ridiculously difficult to read.

Comment: Haha thanks, I write ugly code...

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `i >= 0` instead of `i < s1.length()` and the same for `j`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the terminating condition for your loop. It has nothing to do with the behavior of the postdecrement operator. You need to exit if either `i` or `j` is negative. Right now it exits only if both are negative. Try using `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

P.S.: The tests for `i<s1.length()` and `j<s2.length()` inside the loop are useless. Both `i` and `j` start out smaller than the respective string lengths and only go down, so the conditions are always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `i` and `j` are guaranteed to be equal (that is `s1.length() = s2.length()` , then you program, though may not be written well, would be at least *OK*.

However, the problem is your `i` and `j` may not be the same number. If, say, `j > i`, then `i` will reach `0` before `j` but the loop will continue. Change your `while` condition from:

```
while(i>=0||j>=0)
```

to

```
while(i>=0&&j>=0)
```